# Is there a way to detect implicit vs. explicit CSS height values in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In jQuery, both `$('#foo').height()` and `$('#foo').css('height')` return a value, even if no height property was explicitly set using CSS. Is there a way to detect if an element doesn't have an explicit height, i.e. it's just being rendered according to its contents?

Here's an example I wrote to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/2/

**EDIT**

To clarify my question further, `$('#foo').css('min-height')` and `$('#foo').css('max-height')` already properly return an empty string if they aren't explicitly set. I am looking for a way to find out whether an explicit `height` value is being set via CSS, or not.

**USE CASE**

I have a script that attempts to make floated elements the same height. It does this by looping over the elements to see which one is the tallest, then applying that height to all of them. In some cases, these elements already have an explicit height set, but the others are rendered implicitly.

I now want to add the ability to undo this, and make everything go back to their original heights. In order to do this, I need to know if the element originally had a height set, or if the height was "auto". Once I can do this, I can store the original value in the data collection for the element and then use that to revert to the original height later.

Comment: nice question. my initial thoughts are that this is not simple, but im interested in seeing the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552382/find-out-if-html-height-is-set-by-style-or-by-content

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent

Comment: Thanks for the suggested links. That lead me to wonder if comparing `$('#foo').css('height') == $('#foo')[0].style.height` would work. Is `.style` available cross browser?

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 The `style` property is available across all browsers, but it's not what you think. `.style.height` will only be set if the `style` attribute provides a `height` value. It will not be set if the element has a `class` that sets a `height` value. `style` is probably not the way to go

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I see now it only works with inline styles.

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/strikernl/y3P3A/   and also my answer

Comment: styles can come from so many places, it would be hard to define what "explicitly set" means. what with the cascaded classes and tags, min-height, zoom, border, padding, etc all affecting the height and all...

Comment: Good point @dandavis. In this case, I'd be satisfied knowing only if a height property has been defined directly on the object.

Comment: I added a use case above to further clarify my issue.

Comment: Can't you just do `elem.style.height = 0` on all your floating elements ?

Comment: See my answer on similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140177/1245149)

Answer (score 2):

In some old versions of jQuery it was possible:

http://jsfiddle.net/strikernl/y3P3A/

but now you should just use a function like:

```
function sizeDefined(obj){
   var tmp = obj.clone().html('').appendTo($('body'));
    var w = (tmp.width()==0  ? "no":"yes");
    var h = (tmp.height()==0  ? "no":"yes");
    tmp.remove();
   return  [w,h];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/12/

Comment: This returns false negative if there is a min-height but no height. http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/5/

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 how about now?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/9/ I think because the cloned element is never rendered by the DOM, so there is never any height.

Comment: You can just do `return [tmp.width()==0 && tmp.css('min-width')=='', tmp.height()==0  && tmp.css('min-height')=='']`, there is no need for the ternary assignment.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working accurately. It returns `true` for Outer B even though that only has a `min-height` specified, and it returns `false` for Inner B even though that has a `height` specified

Comment: The link you showed is either wrong, or it isn't fixed.

Comment: Well, http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/16/ is certainly closer, but it's still reporting one false positive: inner_a is reported as having a set height when it doesn't. Thoughts?

Comment: Slight fix to some logic: http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/17/ (still reporting false positive)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you get rid of the content of an element and measure its height it will equate to 0, *unless* it has a height set previously (as a style). So by that reasoning:

```
 function hasSetHeight(elem){
    var html=elem.html();
    elem.html('');
    height = elem.height();
    elem.html(html);
    return (height > 0);
}
```

deletes all content of the element, measures its height and returns true or false if the element has a set height or not.

Comment: Why did this get down voted? It seemed to work when I tested it, though  was wondering if it would lead to content flashing in and out on large pages. http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/4/

Comment: It probably got downvoted because you merely provided code. You provided no explanation.

Comment: This seems to work, but only if the element you are measuring has already been rendered in the DOM. If you try doing it on an element that hasn't been added to the DOM, it will always report false even if an explicit height has been set. It works for my purposes, but figured I'd mention it in case anyone else comes along looking.

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 Is there anything else that could be improved?

Comment: Actually, I'm testing this again and it doesn't work after all. See http://jsfiddle.net/Enn6p/11/ It returns `true` for Outer B even though that only has a `min-height` specified, and it returns `false` for Inner B even though that has a `height` specified.

Comment: @Chrisbloom7 So you want only height specified, not min or max?

Comment: `$('#foo').css('min-height')` and `$('#foo').css('max-height')` already properly return an empty string if they aren't explicitly set. I want to find out if there is an explicit $('#foo').css('height') value.

Comment: I am going to make a new answer.