# scrollHeight is more than clientHeight, even without scrolling content

Tags: javascript, css

I have a piece of JS code that determines whether there is a vertical scrollbar and applies a CSS class to an element. Nothing big.
What is confusing me is it appears to be doing the opposite of what I understand it should be doing. This isn't a problem unless it is a bug and is fixed in the future.
The code:

```
if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight) {
    var d = document.getElementById("footer").className = "footernoscroll";
}
```

My understanding is that it will apply the class if there is a vertical scroll bar, but it appears to be applying the class if there **isn't** a scroll bar. Am I interpreting this correctly and the code is acting strangely or is my interpretation wrong?

**EDIT:** Thought I should add, if I reverse the operator the effects will be reversed and it will use the `else` part of the statement instead.

Comment: scrollHeight and clientHeight should be the same if the body is full height or higher, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: Try `window.innerHeight` `document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight`

Comment: see [my working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71170105/3591273) to determine if an element is **actually scrollable**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your body is 100% of the window height. If you don't have this then the `clientHeight` value will be the combined height of the items within `body` and not the full window height, whereas `scrollHeight` *will* be the full height of the window.

Here's a fiddle that shows it working (open dev tools and view console): http://jsfiddle.net/alexcoady/c53d7q27/1/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[clientHeight documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)
[scrollHeight documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

Comment: I added `height: 100%;` to the body and this appears to have changed nothing, although your JS fiddle works. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: @LockeDonohoe it needs to be on `html` also.

Comment: I realised this right after I posted, decided to test it, and I finally managed to get it to work by changing the operator to `<=`, what it should be for the script to work as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

> The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum clientHeight the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewpoint without using a vertical scrollbar.

Taken from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

So it means the values are the same if there is no scrollbar, and `scrollHeight` is greater when there is one.